# Mysql convert row to column with varchar value

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have table like this:

```
+-------+------------+---------+-------------------------+
| Id    | Mission    | Status  | Time                    |
+-------+------------+---------+-------------------------+
| 1     | Mission 1  | Start   | 2020-06-01 09:50:00     |
| 2     | Mission 1  | Running | 2020-06-01 10:50:00     |
| 3     | Mission 1  | Stop    | 2020-06-01 11:50:00     |
+-------+------------+---------+-------------------------+
```

and my expect output is

```
+------------+-------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| Mission    | Start                   | Running             | Stop                |
+------------+-------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| Mission 1  | 2020-06-01 09:50:00     | 2020-06-01 10:50:00 | 2020-06-01 11:50:00 |
+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

I found some questions related to my problem but those are not exactly work with mine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL row value as column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231312/sql-row-value-as-column-name)

Comment: 3 subqueries, each for separate Status, joined by Mission to a subquery which gets distinct missions list. PS. (Mission, Status) must be defined as UNIQUE in source table.

Comment: @Rich Look carefully on DBMS tags.

Comment: ... and again somebody upvotes "Does this answer your question?" referenced to a topic which is ABSOLUTELY non-applicable. What are you looking by?

Comment: @Rich I think that question and answer are for Sql Server which has pivot function

Comment: @Akina I have considered your solution but I try to find shorter version

Comment: Shorter version provided by **juergen d** may be less effective due to grouping (depends on table structure and statistic, must be tested).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select mission, 
       max(case when status = 'Start' then time end) as `Start`,
       max(case when status = 'Running' then time end) as Running,
       max(case when status = 'Stop' then time end) as Stop
from your_table
group by mission
```